# Protractor unable to find manually bootstrapped angular app

Tags: protractor

I am having trouble getting protractor(v5.0) to recognize a manually bootstrapped angular v1.5.3 app. It does not seem to be using ng-app. Here is the setup of the app:

```
import myAppModule from 'myApp.app';
angular.element(document).ready(() => {
  angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('myApp'), [myAppModule]);
});
```

I tried setting rootElement to '#myApp' but that didn't work. Tried doing a simple check at the moment:

```
browser.get('my.example.com');
browser.waitForAngular();
```

Increasing the wait time does not seem to fix the issue. It times out on waitforAngular.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Pretty strange.

99% of the cases you don't need to call `browser.waitForAngular()` manually, since it is included before almost every action that protractor does.
Can you find element with `ng-app` attribute in HTML? Maybe it is inside `iframe` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the app had check in angular that had a timeout of 6 mins. That kept angular busy which caused my test to timeout since it was waiting on angular to complete its tasks.